# Best way of transferring Excel to ABAP and vice versa

Tags: excel, abap

What is the latest way to export and import data to/from Excel from SAP ABAP? I used some old OLE libraries but they have some limitations. One other thing I found was the SOFFICEINTEGRATION package, but that looks like was developed in the early 00's. Are there any new developments or should I just stick with OLE or SOFFICEINTEGRATION?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the official SAP solution is the two you described above. However there is abap2xlsx, as a freeware. This has to be implemented separately in your system (probably someone responsible in your company won't agree, implementing "random" stuff in productive business system). You can read more about it here:
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/abap2xlsx
(I used it only once, creating an xlsx file and worked very well.)

Comment: You can find installation instructions for ABAP2XLSX at https://github.com/ivanfemia/abap2xlsx You will also have to install abapgit to complete the installation and if you're on an old abap version you may need to install using saplink.

Answer (score 2):

Share some of my experience about Excel handling in ABAP.

1.Excel download from internal table.

```
data:
  lo_table type ref to cl_salv_table,
  lx_xml   type xstring.

try.
    cl_salv_table=>factory(
    importing
      r_salv_table = lo_table
    changing
      t_table      = lt_data ).   "lt_data is your internal table
  catch cx_salv_msg.
endtry.

lx_xml = lo_table->to_xml( xml_type = '10' ). "XLSX

call function 'XML_EXPORT_DIALOG'
  exporting
    i_xml                      = lx_xml
    i_default_extension        = 'XLSX'
    i_initial_directory        = ''
    i_default_file_name        = 'export.XLSX'
    i_mask                     = 'Excel (*.XLSX)|*.XLSX'
  exceptions
    application_not_executable = 1
    others                     = 2.
```

2.Excel upload to internal table.

Function module `ALSM_EXCEL_TO_INTERNAL_TABLE`. See the example [link](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Uploading+Excel+Sheet+to+internal+table+and+displaying+it+in+ALV+Grid) here.

Comment: Hi Allen, I worked with ALSM_EXCEL_TO_INTERNAL_TABLE, it's made using OLE and in my opinion it has some bugs in it. For example somewhere at the end has the following comment: * quit Excel and free ABAP Object - unfortunately, this does not kill the Excel process . Actually that's because the developer was not using the Excel visible and Excel wanted to ask if you want to save the file, that's why the process remained open. One solution is to close it with the messages suppressed like this: SET PROPERTY OF application 'DisplayAlerts' = 0. ... and then CALL METHOD OF application 'QUIT'.