# How to read an .xlsx file stored in the application server into an ABAP internal table?

Tags: excel, file, abap, application-server, internal-tables

I have an Excel (`.xlsx`) file stored in a known path in `AL11` which consists of, let's say, 20 columns and 51 rows of data (one of those rows is the column description which is already known to me because it is fixed and therefore can be ignored). I have created a program with the purpose of reading that Excel file and transferring the data into an internal table.

In a similar case in which the file was stored on local computer, I had used the function module `ALSM_EXCEL_TO_INTERNAL_TABLE` which worked fine, but I do not think it is the appropriate way to use now that the file is stored in the application server.

A colleague of mine suggested using `OPEN DATASET` statement, but in the past I have only used that statement for reading `.txt` format files and I do not know whether it can be used for `.xlsx` files as well or not. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384802/best-way-of-transferring-excel-to-abap-and-vice-versa/48385154#48385154

Comment: I cannot really implement an external service like abap2xlsx because my zprogram is designed to run in a customer's system, therefore I do not have the authority to install external services.

Comment: Many customers use abap2xlsx. Developers just need to ask: what about installing abap2xlsx so that to create the Z program in 10 minutes, versus spending days. Anyway, if you're an experienced developer and the Excel file is very simple, it's easy to unzip it and read the data from the worksheet file (data stored in XML format).

Comment: abap2xlsx is not external service, it is program for import/export excel files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [abap2xlsx](https://github.com/sapmentors/abap2xlsx) package for Excel import/export operations. It has a lot of feature.

If you are looking minimal reader you can check my [xlsxreader](https://github.com/mkysoft/xlsxreader)

You can see a lot of useful package/tools at [ABAP Open Source Projects](https://dotabap.org/).